# Hibernate 6 - UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sqlite

I'm very new to all this and I don't really know what I'm doing, so forgive me if my problem seems trivial. I'm trying to set up a project using Spring, Hibernate 6 and SQLite and I get en error message and can't find how to solve it. Here it is:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: com.example.demo.Message
at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.getEntityDescriptor(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:388) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:292) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.EntityState.getEntityState(EntityState.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityState(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.persist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:766) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
... 8 common frames omitted
```

Here is the Message class :

```
package com.example.demo;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity; import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue; import jakarta.persistence.Id; import jakarta.persistence.Table;
@Entity @Table(name = "message") public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String text;

    public Message() {};

    public Message(String name) {
        this.text = name;
    }

    public void setText(String name) {
        this.text = name;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Message [text=" + text + "]";
    }
}
```

Here is the SpringBootApplication:

```
package com.example.demo;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoSpringApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoSpringApplication.class, args);
    }

    private static SessionFactory configureSessionFactory() {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration().configure();
        ServiceRegistry sr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(conf.getProperties()).build();
        SessionFactory sf = conf.buildSessionFactory(sr);
        return sf;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        SessionFactory sf = configureSessionFactory();
        Session session = sf.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
                Message message1 = new Message("Message one");
                Message message2 = new Message("Message two");
                Message message3 = new Message("Message three");
                session.persist(message1);
                session.persist(message2);
                session.persist(message3);
                session.getTransaction().commit();

                List<Message> messages = session.createQuery("from Message", Message.class).list();
                messages.forEach(m -> {
                    System.out.println("Print message text : " + m.getText());
                });
            session.close();
        sf.close();
    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.community.dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.sqlite.JDBC</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:test-spring.db</property>
        <property name="connection.username"></property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping class="com.example.demo.Message"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
}
group = 'xxxx' version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
java {
    sourceCompatibility = '20'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter' testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:6.3.1.Final'
    implementation 'org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-community-dialects:6.3.0.Final'
}
tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
tasks.named("jar") {
    enabled = false
}
```